# 2 jetways for arrival of international flight at Newark?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, ewr, short-connections

Im flying from Mumbai to Newark on a 777. I am the last seat on the plane. I would like to be able to be one of the first passengers to get out on arrival, because I have exactly 1.5 hour layover for my connecting flight. That's 1.5 hours to get off the plane, go through immigration, customs, security again and find my gate (nearly impossible). At some airports big planes are connected by at least two jetways, making it possible to leave from the backdoor. Is this also the case at Newark?

Comment: Immigration wait times at Newark are typically very short, less than 30 minutes, except for flights arriving in the early afternoon. Since your flight arrives in the early morning, you should not really have much problem making this connection. If your inbound flight is delayed, ask the airline staff for assistance making the connection.

Comment: 1.5 hours should be absolute fine, assuming you personally don't have uncommon delays or issues at immigration. I typically do that whole shebang in 30 - 45 minutes (but not sitting in the last row).

Answer (score 7):

I have never seen two jetways at the front and the back at any US or EU airport. I have seen on occassion steps used by cheapskate EU low cost airlines but never jetways. So the answer is no.

Edit: apparently, not only cheapskate airlines do this. Also note "front and back" -- double jetways are not unheard of (the premium passengers get a separate one) and the A380 sometimes gets three https://youtu.be/sUZ86Z3GZiY?t=1m12s but those are all front and Newark is not A380 certified anyways so we are getting slightly off topic.

Comment: Agreed. This is not possible at Newark.

Comment: You can confirm the story for EWR by looking at the Google Map Aerial View: https://goo.gl/maps/o6ZQgJKNqMJ2.  Note that you don't see two jetways at any gate.  More generally, though, I've seen two jetways used at LHR and SFO, but both at the front of the plane (one is for premium classes).  And I've disembarked using steps from a UA flight at FRA.

Comment: @NateEldredge did they use steps on both ends?

Comment: I believe they did.  You can see [here](https://goo.gl/maps/ZwZkiSXDmHt) an LH plane at FRA with steps at the front and rear, with a bus for passengers at each end.

Answer (score 2):

Overwing jetways are very, very rare, and as far as I know, there aren't any at Newark. Schipol is famous for having them at some gates, and there are/were a few (very limited) experiments at some US airports ([one of which ended in disaster with the jetway collapsing on the wing of an aircraft](http://www.denverpost.com/business/ci_7324922)).

Exit via the rear door usually only happens when disembarking via stairs or elevated buses (which would be even worse for you). Not sure if that ever happens at EWR.

Comment: Here's a link http://www.denverpost.com/business/ci_7324922 about United aborting their attempt in Denver after said collapse.

Comment: Here's a photo of the Schipol http://www.airliners.net/photo//1256812/L/ double bridges. This forum thread http://www.wings900.com/vb/1-1-civil-aviation/72373-what-point-ams-overwing-jetways.html mentions most will be removed and only B747-400 (L2 and L4), MD-11 (L2 and L4) and B777-300ER (L2 and L4) can use them and someone working the bridges at AMS corroborates: http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/5537122/